# EasyAdmin Using your Own Templates Problem

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4, easyadmin

I am trying to override "new" template for EasyAdmin but system ignores template code.
Here is the relevant part of **easy_admin.yaml**

```
entities:
       # List the entity class name you want to manage
      Places:
          class: App\Entity\Places
          templates:
              list: 'asdfasdf'
```

As you see, value of list attribute is invalid but system ignores it and works without error and i can not override the template.

Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide more information? How you trying to override it, where you putting your new template?

Comment: Actually i am putting template, templates folder and trying to call with its name as described at https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html but as you can see above code system ignores the templates section, so i am writing random chars and it doesn't give any error this template cannot be found.

Comment: Just tested now on my project. With random chars in `template` it doesn't give errors for me too. But with correct path - it works fine. In example, my template is in `templates/admin/dashboard.html.twig`, and `list: 'admin/dashboard.html.twig'` works as expected.

Comment: Let me try. I am testing with random chars because i couldn't make the templates work so i thought there is a problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I couldn't find enough information about directory structure about template so i was placed my template in templates folder root and tried to call in yaml file via folder structure. But when i tried as you said it worked.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in the comment - for some reason easyadmin doesn't give any errors if specified template doesn't exists. So, you just need to place your new template in `templates` folder, in example, `templates/admin/listPlaces.html.twig` and then specify correct path in easyadmin's config file, in example:

```
entities:
    Places:
        class: App\Entity\Places
        templates:
             list: 'admin/listPlaces.html.twig'
```

Comment: try using PhpStorm function to cmd+click on the path, if it doesn't take you to the file, then it is probably a wrong path

Answer (score 1):

If you use EasyAdmin 3.x, for that you can overwrite a specific template specifying it in your entity's Controller or you can create your own folder structures like symfony does.

In this example I am overwriting only the edit template for my 'studient' entity, if you want to change all the edits of your project you must do so by creating the folder structure as symfony does.

```
public function configureCrud(): Crud
{
    return Crud::new()
       
        ->overrideTemplate('crud/edit', 'studient/edit.html.twig')
    ;
}
```

You can even combine both methods. Suppose that in addition to modifying only the template **'edit'** of studient you want to modify the way in which easyadmin displays the **flash messages** for that you only have to create this structure in your templates folder: **"templates\bundles\EasyAdminBundles\flash_messages.html.twig"**

I leave the link with the documentation for EasyAdmin 3.x
[overriding-templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/design.html#overriding-templates)